# Workflow changing Title an Name of the file

Tags: workflow-variable

Workflow changing Title an Name of the file.
in order to change file name including file extension what need to do

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 SPWeb tmpweb = workflowProperties.Web;
SPSite site = new SPSite(tmpweb.Url);
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList myList = workflowProperties.Web.Lists["samplelist"];
SPListItem myItem =myList.GetItemById(workflowProperties.ItemId);
myItem.Name  = "Custom Name" //Name contains with file extension
```